# Do corner points optimise a linear function over a bounded convex region?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

1. This proof says if $Z_P \ne Z_Q$...

---

> [image]

---

...then $Z$ is maximised (or minimised, I guess) at one of the $\color{red}{\text{endpoints}}$ -- of what exactly? $\overline{PQ}$? So the maximum value of $Z$ occurs at either $P$ or $Q$?

---

2. Is the last statement in the $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ boxes below supposed to say 'will be maximised' rather than 'will increase'?
3. Is the statement (either original or revised to 'increased') justified by the statement indicated by the $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$ boxes? There's no statement like 'by our result above' sooooo.......

---

> [image]

---

Both screenshots from Chapter 2 [here](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21ABIU1apSS8r3CbA&id=5EA51B764D593198%212679&cid=5EA51B764D593198).

Comment: The proof is pretty clear. Yeah, endpoints of the closed segment $PQ$. Yes, the max of $Z$ restricted to this closed segment occurs at $P$ or $Q$.

Comment: Thanks @dohmatob ^-^ Added another question. Maybe you can then post as answer?

Comment: Oh, what is a corner point? Is that an extreme point? For example, what are the corner points of a closed disk?

Comment: @orangeskid [Context](https://vvcshw.bn1302.livefilestore.com/y3m_Ppo1GwdwBK55xMCw8QN8tb0DAITFzzGB9YM0Ps1Fe0DUxbq6uU4vSfXuWgoSRz9jF4MA1ijAtbIsptdmOjVcCskY07_PGEHmyzGmdb34s0EpJvxIzZ2SbHYeqhR_F-f85OTjcWApyT-mCnYQwQEIg/ma195j14notes_2014second_lp.pdf?psid=1)?